# Phil Sturgeons Rest Server returning 412

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest

Okay, another API question.

I have the following in my Rest Server with one application.

```
public function hire_get()
{
  echo $_GET['name'];
}
```

And then I have the following in another application that is running the Rest Client

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->library('rest', array(
        'server' => 'https://mywebsite.com/api/',
    ));

}

public function hireRequest()
{
    $response = $this->rest->post('requests/hire?name=MitchEvans');

    echo $response;

    $this->rest->debug();
}
```

Now when I call the function `hireRequest` by my web browser, I get the results of the `$this->rest->debug()` as below:

It get's `No Response` with an error of: `The requested URL returned error: 412` I searched the code 412 for HTTP Requests and it says it a `precondition failed error`. Is this something with my web server? How do I get around this or how do I solve this issue?

I think it is worth noting that if I call the `hire_get` function directly from a web page like so: `http://www.mywebsite.com/api/requests/hire?name=My Awesome Name` it works just fine and echoes out `My Awesome Name` but it's once I try to access it through another web application it gives me the error.

Even if I switch everything to a post I still receive the 412 error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your Rest Client call from a `post` to a `get` since your Rest Server function is a `hire_get`

If you are wanting to post data instead, your rest server needs to be changed to `hire_post`

Refrencing the GitHub Page for the Rest Server:

https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver

```
Accessing parameters is also easy. Simply use the name of the HTTP verb as a method:

$this->get('blah'); // GET param
$this->post('blah'); // POST param
$this->put('blah'); // PUT param
```

About a quarter of the way down the Read Me!

Comment: Even if I switch everything to a `post` I still receive the `412` error.

Comment: Had to call the server by `https`

Comment: Why are you talking to yourself?